# Ticketing system URLs (Manage Engine, Service Now, OTRS)

Tags: python, servicenow, otrs, ticket-system

I have an app where a person can create a ticket for the system he has configured. We then want to show the link to this ticket in the HTML page. I assume the link is some static part + the id of the ticket. We can't find these links as we don't have any testing support to check for ourselves.

The ticketing systems are Manage Engine, Service Now and OTRS. I got the idea of URL of Service now URL of a ticket (https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=dfc607a5db1cdbc01dcaf3231f9619b8)  but didn't find any information on OTRS and Manage Engine tickets URL.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve or what you have. Maybe if you started with one task first and not three at once it would help.

Comment: Hi, we basically want to provide the link to the ticket which one can click and can be easily redirected. We allow users to create ticket in app.

Comment: Yes, then do this. Please, ask yourself what people here know of what you're doing and how much info is required! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt , Thanks. Made the edits.

Answer (score 1):

For the ((OTRS)) Community Edition exists two URL, one for agents and one for customer:

- Agent: http://FQDN/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketNumber=xx
- Customer: http://FQDN/otrs/customer.pl?Action=CustomerTicketZoom;TicketNumber=xx

Where xx ist the TicketNumber, not ID.